# Length of a 2D Array inside a HashMap

Tags: java

I am having a little bit of trouble figuring out some complicated logic required for a program at work.

This program is designed to compare "transactions" between two folders. Each folder can contain any number of files and each file (XML Document) can contain any number of transactions. Each transaction will have 5 tags.

I must compare two folders and see if any transactions match.

To do this, I am using a `HashMap` and putting a `String[][]` array inside of it. Each key in the `HashMap` will represent 1 file. The row in the String will represent a transaction and the columns will represent the tags.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to access the `String[][]` from within the `HashMap`. I need to get the number of transactions (rows).

Here is how I do the above:

```
// Creating the HashMap and Array[][]
public static Map<Integer, String[][]> Pain008TransactionsCollection = new HashMap();
public static String[][] Pain008Transactions;

//Here is the logic where I populate the HashMap.
int transactionSize = EndToEndId.size();

//Creates a 2D array with one dimension for each transaction and six dimensions
//for relevant tags + filename.
Pain008Transactions = new String[transactionSize][6];

//For each transaction..
for(int i = 0; i < transactionSize; i++){

    //Below will add each value into the 2D array for each transaction. Note that the
    //filename is also added so that it can be easily associated with a transaction later.
    Pain008Transactions[i][0]=EndToEndId.get(i);
    Pain008Transactions[i][1]=InstdAmt.get(i);
    Pain008Transactions[i][2]=MmbId.get(i);
    Pain008Transactions[i][3]=DbtrNm.get(i);
    Pain008Transactions[i][4]=OthrId.get(i);
    Pain008Transactions[i][5]=GetFiles.pain008Files.get(currentFile).toString();

}

//Puts the 2D array into the collections map at the position of the current 
//file in sequence.
Pain008TransactionsCollection.put(currentFile, Pain008Transactions);

System.out.println(Pain008TransactionsCollection);
```

I know that to get the total number of `HashMap` key's I use this:

```
Pain008TransactionsCollection.size()
```

and I know to get the rows for the String[][] I use

```
Pain008Transactions.length()
```

But I am not sure how to call the `HashMap` key and then get the row length for that particular key.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: You'd better introduce a list of custom objects instead of creation 2D array here. So you can define a class with 6 fields that you need, then store list of the class instances in the list. And don't use raw types, use `new HashMap<>()` instead of `new HashMap()`.

Comment: Look into java coding style guides. Variable names go camelCase (so they never start UpperCase). It is also a bad idea to put something like "collection" into a variable name. Why not "transactionsByIndex" or something like that?!

Comment: And thinking about it: it sounds really **strange** that your map key shall be an Integer? Probably you should step further back, and try to introduce **more** abstractions. For example: a class representing a **transation**. That class knows about the 5 attributes; and has methods to compare two transactions for example. So: get away from low-level 2-dim string arrays. Otherwise you will spend **a lot of time** writing **a lot** of low-level array-manipulating code. That will turn into a maintenance nightmare the minute you close your editor.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback everyone. I am very new to 2D arrays so as you could imagine it's been a challenge to also incorporate it into a HashMap. I may have a solution but I'm not sure if it will work.. Will the following get me back the associated rows? 

ParseACH.ACHTransactionsCollection.get(i).length; j++

Comment: Also @GhostCat - Good idea about the naming. The map key is an interger because I only need it for purposes of the loop and it's easy to call it by number rather than having to call it by string name.

Comment: But it is a **bad** abstraction. You don't do things because they seem convenient on the first glance. Instead, you spent a lot of time thinking about the **best** abstraction that helps you solve your problems the most elegant way. You see, when your map keys are really only indices - than what is the point of using a **map**. Then a ordinary **list** would do, too. Because a **list** is nothing else but a *mapping* function from some index on some data (just more efficient).

Comment: Thanks Ghost. I'm going to look at using separate classes I just didn't consider that option before you mentioned it.. You are correct I'm fairly new at Java I just have a job to do so I do the best I can to figure it out :)

Answer (score 1):

You **iterate** the map, like

```
for (Entry<Integer, String[][]> entry : Pain008TransactionsCollection.entrySet() ) {
  Integer key = entry.getKey();
  String[][] data = entry.getValue();
}
```

Thats it. Or do I miss something?

You retrieve a single value and its dimensions with:

```
String data[][] data = Pain008TransactionsCollection.get(0); 
int rowCount = data.length;
int columnCount = data[0].length;
```

for example.

Comment: That seems like it might be more than needed. I know to simply call a value I can do this: ClearedMainGUI.Transactions.get(ClearedMainGUI.selectedRow)[i][7]=tbl.getValueAt(i, 7).toString(); But the problem remains just getting the actual length of the rows for a specific HashMap array. What about this: ParseACH.ACHTransactionsCollection.get(i).length; j++

Comment: Thanks for proving my comment: the code you just posted is overly **low level**. And if you think my stuff is "too sophisticated"; then I would say: you get it the completely wrong way. The "more sophisticated" (aka rich in abstraction) your code is, the better. And honestly: reading your statements; I start to doubt that you have a good idea of "what is needed". It seems that you have some 10% knowledge of Java - and whatever doesn't fit into that small area ... you reject. And honestly: that is not a good strategy to solve programming problems.

Comment: In other words: you asked how to access KEYS and VALUES of your Map. I told you. So, if that is **not** what you asked for - then what actually is your question; the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I apologize I should have elaborated more. I did actually take your comments to heart and fully understand what you mean. I'm going to look into adding classes for each transaction but as you can imagine I'm on a time-frame so I'm hoping to get this working then I can go back and fix the organization so my team can still use the Jar.

Comment: My question was how to get the length of a specific row in the HashMap. I figured out that you must use .get on the hashmap and then follow that with .length.